# How do I let ag-Grid events read private methods?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ag-grid-angular

I want to make my ag-grid dynamically resize as the window width is changed as well as to destroy the FromEvent when the user leaves.

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {
    ColDef,
    ColumnApi,
    GridApi,
    GridOptions,
    GridReadyEvent,
    IDatasource,
    IGetRowsParams,
    RowClickedEvent,
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import { debounceTime, fromEvent, ReplaySubject, Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';

export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);


    @ViewChild(AgGridAngular)
    agGrid: AgGridAngular;

    public gridOptions: GridOptions = {
        ...,
        onGridReady: this.onGridReady,
    };

    private gridApi: GridApi;
    private columnApi: ColumnApi;

    constructor() {
        console.log('Construct');
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroyed$.next(true);
        this.destroyed$.complete();
    }

    onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
        console.log('gridReady', this.destroyed$);
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
        fromEvent(window, 'resize')
            .pipe(debounceTime(200), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                console.log('Window resizing');
                this.gridApi?.sizeColumnsToFit();
            });

        params.api.setDatasource(this.dataSource);
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}
```

The private destroyed variable prints as:

```
{
    "closed": false,
    "currentObservers": null,
    "observers": [],
    "isStopped": false,
    "hasError": false,
    "thrownError": null,
    "_bufferSize": 1,
    "_windowTime": null,
    "_timestampProvider": {},
    "_buffer": [],
    "_infiniteTimeWindow": true
}
```

inside the onInit but prints as `undefined` inside of the onGridReady event that causes an error in the browser:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `GridOptions`, you'll need to bind `this` to the function, like so:

```
public gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    onGridReady: this.onGridReady.bind(this),
};
```

although, if you prefer, this would also likely work:

```
public gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    onGridReady: (event) => { this.onGridReady(event); },
};
```

Comment: This isn't really a `ag-grid` question as much as it is a Angular/Typescript question, but there you have it. That's how you give functions to external libraries.